# Restore "search hit BOTTOM, continuing at TOP" when search navigation wraps aound end of file

Tags: neovim, search, navigation

I've recently switched to Neovim, and some days in, I realized that there was no `search hit BOTTOM, continuing at TOP` message when jumping from the last to the first search result (or vice versa), which I'm relying on fairly regularly. I did some experimenting and figured out that the current pattern shown in the status bar (e.g., `/\<foo\>`) overwrites the error message.

The message can be restored by silencing the search navigation commands with the following (otherwise empty) config and `--noplugin`:

```
" ~/.config/nvim/init.vim

nnoremap <silent> * *
nnoremap <silent> n n
" ... (omitting backward, g*, etc.)

set shortmess=
" set shortmess+=s  " don't give "search hit BOTTOM, continuing at TOP" ...
```

The problem with this approach is twofold:

- The `search hit BOTTOM...` does not disappear when jumping from the first to the second result after wrap-jumping from the last to the first;
- The current search pattern (and `[i/n]` counter) is no longer shown.

While I still prefer this state to the former, the ideal situation would be as follows:

- The current search result with counter is shown by default after starting a search or jumping between results.
- However, when jumping from the first to the last search result in the file (or vice versa), the message `search hit BOTTOM, continuing at TOP` (or vice versa) is shown instead -- but disappears on further movement, e.g., when jumping on to the second result.

How can this be achieved?

---

PS: I'm running `NVIM V0.4.3` (`LuaJIT 2.0.5`, `Features: +acl +iconv +tui`) on Manjaro Linux.

Comment: It looks like it's an issue with that mapping; it works like that for me in both Vim and neovim. Looks like "make `*` and `#` highlight the match without jumping or any side-effects" is a bit tricky.

Comment: @MartinTournoij No, the original problem of the missing `search hit BOTTOM...` occurs even with a completely empty `init.vim`, and the mapping in the "PS" is not part of the test config in the main part of the question (as I attempted to clarify with "not referring to the test file shown above, of course").

Comment: It's that not part of the problem, then it's probably best to leave it out of the question? It works well with the default settings for me btw (when `nowrapscan` is set), if it doesn't for you then that sounds like a possible bug in neovim?

Comment: Yes you're probably right, I'll remove it.